# How to print values into a Label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a small app that counts net amount and tax. I wrote this code and I've tried many times using `var.set()` based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603169/update-tkinter-label-from-variable) but I have no idea how do it correctly.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def count23():
    b = gross.get()
    n = round(b/1.23, 2)
    v = round(b - n, 2)
    # print here works, but prints in shell 

def count8():
    b = gross.get()
    n = round(b/1.08, 2)
    v = round(b - n, 2)

def count5():
    b = gross.get()
    n = round(b/1.05, 2)
    v = round(b - n, 2)

root = tk.Tk()

gross = DoubleVar()
root.geometry('220x200+250+250')

L1 = Label(root, text='Input gross ammount').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

E1 = Entry(root, textvariable=gross).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)

L2 = Label(root, text='Choose your tax rate').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

B1 = Button(root, text='5 %', command=count5)
B1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

B2 = Button(root, text='8 %', command=count8)
B2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

B3 = Button(root, text='23 %', command=count23)
B3.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

L3 = Label(root, text=' ').grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=5)

L4 = Label(root, text='Net').grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

L5 = Label(root, text='TAX').grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

L6 = Label(root, relief='raised')
L6.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

L7 = Label(root, relief='raised')
L7.grid(row=6, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

root.mainloop()
```

I need to print net and tax in L6 and L7 labels. Give me some clues how do it, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to give those labels their own `textvariable`s.

I replaced your 3 `count` functions with a single function `show_tax`. We use lambda functions in each Button command to call `show_tax` with the desired tax rate. I've also made a few other minor changes.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_tax(rate):
    b = gross.get()
    n = round(b / rate, 2)
    # Format to string with 2 digits after the decimal point
    net.set(format(n, '.2f'))
    t = round(b - n, 2)
    tax.set(format(t, '.2f'))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('310x165+250+250')
root.title('Tax calculator')

gross = tk.DoubleVar()
net = tk.StringVar()
tax = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label(root, text='Input gross amount').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=gross)
e.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)

tk.Label(root, text='Choose your tax rate').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='5 %', command=lambda r=1.05: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='8 %', command=lambda r=1.08: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='23 %', command=lambda r=1.23: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

# An empty Label to force row to be displayed
tk.Label(root).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=5)

tk.Label(root, text='Net').grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')
tk.Label(root, text='TAX').grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=net, relief='raised')
l.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=tax, relief='raised')
l.grid(row=6, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

root.mainloop()
```

---

I have a couple more comments on your code (and my changes to it).

It's not a good idea to use `from tkinter import *` as that imports about 130 Tkinter names into the global namespace, which is messy and can lead to name collisions. Using the explicit `tk.` form makes the code easier to read.

BTW, the Widget `.grid` and `.pack` methods return `None`. So when you do something like

```
L2 = Label(root, text='Choose your tax rate').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)
```

it creates the label, puts it into the grid, and then sets `L2` to `None`. If you need to keep a reference to the label you need to create the widget & place it into the grid in two steps, like this:

```
L2 = Label(root, text='Choose your tax rate')
L2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)
```

If you *don't* need to keep a reference to the widget, but you still want to split it over 2 lines to keep the line length short then just use a "throwaway" variable, like I have with `e`, `b`, and `l`.

---

As  Bryan Oakley mentions in the comments we don't actually need to give those labels their own StringVar `textvariable`s: we can directly update their `text`s using the widget's `.config` method.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_tax(rate):
    b = gross.get()
    n = round(b / rate, 2)
    # Format to string with 2 digits after the decimal point
    L6.config(text=format(n, '.2f'))
    t = round(b - n, 2)
    L7.config(text=format(t, '.2f'))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('310x165+250+250')
root.title('Tax calculator')

gross = tk.DoubleVar()

tk.Label(root, text='Input gross amount').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=gross)
e.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)

tk.Label(root, text='Choose your tax rate').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='5 %', command=lambda r=1.05: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='8 %', command=lambda r=1.08: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

b = tk.Button(root, text='23 %', command=lambda r=1.23: show_tax(r))
b.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

# An empty Label to force row to be displayed
tk.Label(root).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=5)

tk.Label(root, text='Net').grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')
tk.Label(root, text='TAX').grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

L6 = tk.Label(root, relief='raised')
L6.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

L7 = tk.Label(root, relief='raised')
L7.grid(row=6, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You very much for this answer. Ive tried with 3 different textvariables but never thought using lambda. Its new thing for me. And thanks for comments. I like when someone tells me what im doing wrong

Comment: _"The simple way to do this is to give those labels their own textvariables."_ - an even simpler way is to NOT give labels their own textvariables. You can directly update the labels without the need for the variable objects. Fewer objects == less complexity. Less complexity == easier to maintain.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Good points. I've added a new version that does that.

Comment: @guest013 I'm glad you like it. Please see the new improved version.

Comment: @PM2Ring i must say that both solutions are good. They differ two code lines but they give me better knowledge than i had before. Now i know how set label in two ways - simple way and even simpler :) I will use .config in my other project right after i can handle .after method ;)