# Tkinter update label with var text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a label that updates every time a file is selected from a  filedialog. I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603169/update-tkinter-label-from-variable) but I somehow started created multiple windows. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.select_history = tk.Button(self,text="Select  Student History File",command=self.select_history).pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",command=root.destroy).pack(side="top")

        tk.Label(root, textvariable=historyfile).pack(side="bottom")        


    def select_history(self):
        fname = fd.askopenfilename()
        historyfile.set(fname)
        print(fname)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x450+0+0")
root.configure(background="lightblue")

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `historyfile` is undefined. Change `tk.Label(root, textvariable=historyfile).pack(side="bottom")` to

```
self.historyfile = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.historyfile).pack(side="bottom")
```

In the function `select_history`, use

```
self.historyfile.set(fname)
```

Total code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.select_history = tk.Button(self,text="Select  Student History File",command=self.select_history).pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",command=root.destroy).pack(side="top")
        self.historyfile = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.historyfile).pack(side="bottom")        


    def select_history(self):
        fname = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.historyfile.set(fname)
        print(fname)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x450+0+0")
root.configure(background="lightblue")

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```