# Tkinter Label not updating across classes (another one)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

**Goal:** Display variable across classes

**Issue:** Updating labels, specifically line 99

**Errors:** Logical only

**Environment:**
Python 3.6.9, Tk 8.6.8, OS Ubuntu 18.04

**Write up:**

I am trying to display variable `pPanelSettings.cutLength` in the `pViewSettings` class on line 99 of the included code, however I can not get it to update/refresh. Including `textvariable` in any of my labels makes it display blank, even though I give them an initial value. In the included attempt, I left in a non-functioning refresh command (line 106) as well as a non-functioning attempt to trace (line 107). Other attempts have included:

`update_idletasks`,
creating an additional string variable that simply reformatted the integer variable just to confirm that wasn't the issue,
referencing `pViewSettings` and `pPanelSettings` inside of each other (caused a loop),
as well as a few others that I am forgetting at this point.

I am most interested in finding out the "why" of whatever I am missing as I will be repeating this process again in the future. Sorry to fill up the forums with another newbie Label question, but I'm just at a loss at this point on my own. I am confident it is a simple fix that I am just completely missing.

Ideally I'd like to understand where I'm going wrong with `textvariable`, as that seems most likely to be the simple solution, but comparing to examples online I am still not seeing where I am wrong.

**Me:**

I was not planning on doing GUI learning until early next year, however my timeline for this project was accelerated so I am having to dive in quick.

**Posts I've gone through:**

[What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks)

[Update Tkinter Label from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603169/update-tkinter-label-from-variable)

https://yagisanatode.com/2018/02/26/how-to-display-and-entry-in-a-label-tkinter-python-3/

Many others, but just lost all my bookmarks.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as time
import math as math

#create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('machine')

#create main container
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)

#layout main container, grow with window size
mainFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

#create globals
inchesInFeet = tk.IntVar()
answerReset = tk.IntVar()

#set globals
answerReset.set(0)

#create classes
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class pPanelSettings(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #create variables
        self.cutFeet = tk.IntVar()
        self.cutInches = tk.IntVar()
        self.cutLength = tk.IntVar()
        self.panelCutConfirm = tk.BooleanVar()
        #set variables
        self.cutFeet.set(0)
        self.cutInches.set(0)
        self.cutLength.set(0)
        self.panelCutConfirm.set(0)
        #widgets
        self.pageTitle = tk.Label(self, text='PANEL SETTINGS')
        self.panelBlock = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.panelLabel = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text='CURRENT PANEL SET LENGTH')
        self.panelSetting = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text=self.cutLength.get())
        self.messageDisplay = tk.Label(self, text='Set cut length (feet):')
        self.wYesNo = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bYes = tk.Button(self.wYesNo, text='ENTER', command=self.setCutFeet, height=4, activebackground='green1', background='green2')
        self.response = tk.Entry(self, justify='center')
        #layout
        self.pageTitle.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.panelBlock.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=5)
        self.panelLabel.pack(side='left', fill='x', padx=50)
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
        self.messageDisplay.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=60)
        self.wYesNo.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)
        self.bYes.pack(side='left', fill='both', padx=10, expand=True)
        self.response.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=60)
        #settings
        self.response.focus_set()

    def clearText(self):
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')

    def transition(self):
        self.after(2000, self.pageReset)
        
    def pageReset(self): #resets widgets to initial view
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Set cut length (feet):')
        self.response.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=60)
        self.wYesNo.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)
        self.bYes.config(command=self.setCutFeet)
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
      
    def setCutFeet(self):
        self.cutFeet.set(int(self.response.get()))
        self.setCutConfirm()
     
    def setCutConfirm(self):
        self.panelCutConfirm.set(True)
        self.cutLength.set(self.cutFeet.get())
        self.panelSetting.config(text=self.cutLength.get())
        print(self.cutLength.get())  ##verification test point using shell
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Panel cut length set.')
        self.wYesNo.pack_forget()
        self.transition()
        
class pViewSettings(Page): ##this page needs auto update/refresh to display current settings from other pages
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #pages to objects
        oPanelSettings = pPanelSettings(self)
        #widgets
        self.pageTitle = tk.Label(self, text='VIEW SETTINGS')
        self.panelBlock = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.panelLabel = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text='PANEL LENGTH')
        self.panelSetting = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text=oPanelSettings.cutLength.get())
        #layout
        self.pageTitle.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.panelBlock.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=5)
        self.panelLabel.pack(side='left', fill='x', padx=50)
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
        #actions
        self.refreshSelf() ##i know that this doesn't work, but i do not understand why
        oPanelSettings.cutLength.trace('r', self.refreshSelf) ##i really feel like this should work though

    def refreshSelf(self):
        #pages to objects
        oPanelSettings = pPanelSettings(self)
        #action
        self.after(1000, self.refreshSelf)
        self.panelSetting.config(text=oPanelSettings.cutLength.get())

class pMainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #pages to objects
        oPanelSettings = pPanelSettings(self)
        oViewSettings = pViewSettings(self)

        #create menu and view windows
        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonFrame.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=False) #menu column
        container.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=True) #main view window

        #place page objects into main view window
        oPanelSettings.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        oViewSettings.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
        #create menu buttons
        bPanelSettings = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='Panel Settings', command=oPanelSettings.lift)
        bViewSettings = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='View Settings', command=oViewSettings.lift)
        
        #menu layout
        bPanelSettings.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        bViewSettings.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        
        #startup display page
        oViewSettings.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    oMainView = pMainView(root)
    oMainView.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry('1024x600')
    root.mainloop()
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Someone call Bryan Oakley to save me! :) :)

EDIT #1: Shortened code towards minimal reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may find this in *the future* - I ended up just using the globals and added a self looping refresh. The attached code is not the "minimal reproduction" because I did not feel like scrubbing it down, but it is all there. I kind of understand that it is better to pull variables from where they are set, but I do not understand how globals are any different from using the shared data example given here (just go absorb anything Bryan Oakley posts) [How to access variables from different classes in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter) .

Line 16/19 - define and initially set global variable

Line 123 - update global variable (class pPanelSettings)

Line 148 - initial display (class pViewSettings)

Line 155 - begin refresh (class pViewSettings)

Line 159 - just a duplicate of L148

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as time
import math as math

#create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Fabric Marker')

#create main container
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)

#layout main container, grow with window size
mainFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

#define variables
cutLength = tk.IntVar()

#set variables
cutLength.set(0)

#define constants
answerReset = tk.IntVar()

inchesInFeet = tk.IntVar()
inch = tk.IntVar()

#set constants
answerReset.set(0)

inchesInFeet.set(12)
inch.set(1)

#create classes
class Page(tk.Frame): ###I NEED NOTES TO UNDERSTAND THIS ONE ENTIRELY###
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class pPanelSettings(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #define variables
        self.cutFeet = tk.IntVar()
        self.cutInches = tk.IntVar()
        self.setCutConfirm = tk.BooleanVar()
        #set variables
        self.cutFeet.set(0)
        self.cutInches.set(0)
        self.setCutConfirm.set(False)
        #widgets
        self.pageTitle = tk.Label(self, text='PANEL SETTINGS')
        self.panelBlock = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.panelLabel = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text='CURRENT PANEL SET LENGTH')
        self.panelSetting = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text=(str(str(cutLength.get()) + '" / ' + str(self.cutFeet.get()) + '\' ' + str(self.cutInches.get()) + '"')))
        self.messageDisplay = tk.Label(self, text='Set cut length (feet):')
        self.outputDisplay = tk.Label(self)
        self.wYesNo = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bYes = tk.Button(self.wYesNo, text='ENTER', command=self.setCutFeet, height=4, activebackground='green1', background='green2')
        self.bNo = tk.Button(self.wYesNo, text='CLEAR', command=self.clearText, height=4, activebackground='red1', background='red2')
        self.response = tk.Entry(self, justify='center')
        #layout
        self.pageTitle.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.panelBlock.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=5)
        self.panelLabel.pack(side='left', fill='x', padx=50)
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
        self.messageDisplay.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=60)
        self.wYesNo.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)
        self.bYes.pack(side='left', fill='both', padx=10, expand=True)
        self.bNo.pack(side='right', fill='both', padx=10, expand=True)
        self.response.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=60)
        #settings
        self.response.focus_set()

    def clearText(self):
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')

    def confirmTransition(self):
        self.after(2000, self.pageReset)
        
    def pageReset(self):
        self.cutFeet.set(answerReset.get())
        self.cutInches.set(answerReset.get())
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')
        self.outputDisplay.pack_forget()
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Set cut length (feet):')
        self.wYesNo.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)
        self.bYes.config(command=self.setCutFeet)
        self.bNo.config(command=self.clearText)
        self.response.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=60)
        self.outputDisplay.config(foreground='black')
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
      
    def setCutFeet(self):
        self.cutFeet.set(int(self.response.get()))
        self.enterCutInches()

    def enterCutInches(self):
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')
        self.bYes.config(command=self.verifyInches)
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Set cut length (inches):')

    def verifyInches(self):
        if (int(self.response.get()) >= (inchesInFeet.get())):
            self.response.delete(0, 'end')
            self.messageDisplay.config(text='Enter a number less than 12')
            return
        else:
            self.setCutInches()

    def setCutInches(self):
        self.cutInches.set(int(self.response.get()))
        self.response.delete(0, 'end')
        self.response.pack_forget()
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Is this the correct cut length?')
        self.bYes.config(command=self.setPanelCut)
        self.bNo.config(command=self.pageReset)
        self.outputDisplay.config(text=str(str((self.cutFeet.get() * inchesInFeet.get()) + self.cutInches.get()) + '" / ' + str(self.cutFeet.get()) + '\' ' + str(self.cutInches.get()) + '"'))
        self.outputDisplay.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', padx=20, pady=60)
        
    def setPanelCut(self):
        self.setCutConfirm.set(True)
        cutLength.set((self.cutFeet.get() * inchesInFeet.get()) + self.cutInches.get())
        self.panelSetting.config(text=(str(str(cutLength.get()) + '" / ' + str(self.cutFeet.get()) + '\' ' + str(self.cutInches.get()) + '"')))
        print(cutLength.get())  ##verification test point using shell
        self.messageDisplay.config(text='Panel cut length set.')
        self.outputDisplay.config(foreground='green1', pady=120)
        self.bNo.config(command=self.pageReset)
        self.wYesNo.pack_forget()
        self.confirmTransition()

class pViewSettings(Page):
    #confirm setting options on this page
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #define variables
        setMarkConfirm = tk.BooleanVar()
        setJobConfirm = tk.BooleanVar()
        #set variables
        setMarkConfirm.set(0)
        setJobConfirm.set(0)
        #widgets
        self.pageTitle = tk.Label(self, text='VIEW SETTINGS')
        self.panelBlock = tk.LabelFrame(self, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.panelLabel = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text='PANEL LENGTH')
        self.panelSetting = tk.Label(self.panelBlock, text=str(cutLength.get()) + '" / ' + str(math.trunc(cutLength.get()/inchesInFeet.get())) + '\' ' + str(cutLength.get() - ((math.trunc(cutLength.get()/inchesInFeet.get())) * inchesInFeet.get())) + '"')
        #layout
        self.pageTitle.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.panelBlock.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=5)
        self.panelLabel.pack(side='left', fill='x', padx=50)
        self.panelSetting.pack(side='right', fill='x')
        #action
        self.refreshSelf()

    def refreshSelf(self):
        #action
        self.panelSetting.config(text=str(cutLength.get()) + '" / ' + str(math.trunc(cutLength.get()/inchesInFeet.get())) + '\' ' + str(cutLength.get() - ((math.trunc(cutLength.get()/inchesInFeet.get())) * inchesInFeet.get())) + '"')
        self.after(10, self.refreshSelf)

class pMainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #pages to objects
        oPanelSettings = pPanelSettings(self)
        oViewSettings = pViewSettings(self)

        #create menu and view windows
        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonFrame.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=False) #menu column
        container.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=True) #main view window

        #place page objects into main view window
        oPanelSettings.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        oViewSettings.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
        #create menu buttons
        bPanelSettings = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='Panel Settings', command=oPanelSettings.lift)
        bViewSettings = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='View Settings', command=oViewSettings.lift)
        
        #menu layout
        bPanelSettings.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        bViewSettings.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        #startup display page
        oViewSettings.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    oMainView = pMainView(root)
    oMainView.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry('1024x600')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use StringVar for updating a label is as follows:

This is a minimal example, where you can click the 'Add' button to increase value and change label color between 'red' and 'cyan'.

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
value = 0
labelVar = tk.StringVar()
labelVar.set(f"Current value: {value}")


def add_text():
    global value
    value += 1
    labelVar.set(f"Current value: {value}")
    if value % 2:
        newcolor = 'red'
    else:
        newcolor = 'cyan'
    label.config(bg=newcolor)


label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=labelVar, bg='cyan')
label.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Add', command=add_text).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Clarification please:

My code has `cutLength` defined as `IntVar` on line 36, given an initial value on line 41 in the same manner as your example `labelVar`.

`textvariable` is blanking the label as stated in the original question.