# Button that makes a random generated word appear. Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Pretty basic stuff.  I had this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import secrets

def stuff():
    stuff = ["study math",
             "Phone", "social",
             "study python","tv",
             "exercise"]
    print(secrets.choice(stuff))

window = Tk()

button = Button(window,
                text="click me",
                command=stuff,
                font=("Comic Sans", 40),
                fg="#00FF00",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="#00FF00",
                activebackground="black")

button.grid()
```

But that only prints the listed word on the terminal.  I want to print the word on the GUI as a Label.  I'm trying stuff like this,

```
def stuff():
    stuff = ["study math",
             "Phone", "social",
             "study python","tv",
             "exercise"]
    Label(window, secrets.choice(stuff)).grid(row=1)
```

Butt.. cant quite figure it out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should be `Label(window, text=secrets.choice(stuff)).grid(row=1)`

Comment: You can use a StringVar with Label. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603169/update-tkinter-label-from-variable for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `text` option to set the text of a `Label` widget.  Also suggest to create the label once outside `stuff()` function.

```py
from tkinter import *
import secrets

def stuff():
    stuff = ["study math",
             "Phone", "social",
             "study python","tv",
             "exercise"]
    # update the label with the random choice
    choice.config(text=secrets.choice(stuff))


window = Tk()

button = Button(window,
                text="click me",
                command=stuff,
                font=("Comic Sans", 40),
                fg="#00FF00",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="#00FF00",
                activebackground="black")

button.grid(row=0, column=0) # better to specify row and column

# label to show the random message
choice = Label(window)
choice.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```