# Tkinter hiding characters in a label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm wondering if it's possible to hide characters in a label by replacing them with, for example, an asterisk, like you can in an entry field:

```
A6 = Entry(W_Menu, show = "*", bd = 3)
```

Would it be possible to, for example, use a check button to show characters when selected and replace them with an asterisk when unchecked if the text is in a label? This would be very useful for me. If not, are there any alternatives that do not require an entry field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update

Answer (score 1):

Hope this minimal example gives you an idea of what you can do with labels and texts monitoring the status of the checkbox and linking that status to a string variable.
Of course, you can implement the same with a TextLabel controled by the Checkbox status.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton
from Tkinter import StringVar, IntVar

root = Tk()

name = 'hello'
text = StringVar()
text.set(name)

status = IntVar()

def change():
    # you must implement here the mechanism of change
    # but this serves to show the idea
    if status.get() == 1:   # if clicked
        text.set('****')
    else:
        text.set(name)

cb = Checkbutton(root, textvariable=text, variable=status, command=change)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option for labels.