# Why aren't my Tkinter Labels updating?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

It's my understanding that the class `DiceRoller` should be inheriting from the class `die`, however every time I run I get the error:

```
self.display.config(text = str(self.value))  
AttributeError: 'DiceRoller' object has no attribute 'display'
```

The value of `self.value` is updating, but the Tkinter label is not.

```
import Tkinter
import random

class die(object):
    def __init__(self,value,display):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        self.display = Tkinter.Label(display,
          text = str(self.value),
          font = ('Garamond', 56),
          bg = 'white',
          relief = 'ridge',
          borderwidth = 5)
        self.display.pack(side = 'left')

class DiceRoller(die):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameWin = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.gameWin.title('Dice Roller')
        self.gameFrame = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.dice = []
        self.Row1 = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        for i in range(1,4):
            self.dice.append(die(i,self.Row1))  
        self.topFrame = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.rollBtn = Tkinter.Button(self.topFrame,
            text = 'Roll Again',
            command = self.rollDice,
            font = ('Garamond', 56))
        self.rollBtn.pack(side = 'bottom')

        self.gameFrame.pack()
        self.Row1.pack()
        self.topFrame.pack()
        self.gameWin.mainloop()
    def rollDice(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value  #to show value is in fact changing
        self.display.config(text = str(self.value))

varName = DiceRoller()
```

Comment: You're setting `text = str(self.value)` - that's a one-off, it's not some kind of binding that will get updated when `self.value` changes. Set `textvariable=self.value`, a direct reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making python/tkinter label widget update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that

```
AttributeError: 'DiceRoller' object has no attribute 'display'
```

error because `DiceRoller` doesn't actually have a `.display` attribute.

You may *expect* it to have one because the `die` class has a `.display` attribute, but that attribute gets created when `die.__init__` gets called, and `DiceRoller` won't automatically call `die.__init__` because you've overridden that method with `DiceRoller`'s own `.__init__` method.

If you want to call `die.__init__` inside `DiceRoller.__init__` you can do that, the suggested way is to use the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) function. But you have to be careful to call `die.__init__` with the correct arguments!

However, there's no need for `DiceRoller` to inherit from `die`. I've moved `DiceRoller`'s old `rollDice` method to `die` & created a new `rollDice` method for `DiceRoller`. So when the `'Roll Again'` button is pressed all the dice in `DiceRoller.dice` get rolled.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class die(object):
    def __init__(self, value, display):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        self.display = tk.Label(display,
          text = str(self.value),
          font = ('Garamond', 56),
          bg = 'white',
          relief = 'ridge',
          borderwidth = 5)
        self.display.pack(side = 'left')

    def rollDice(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value  #to show value is in fact changing
        self.display.config(text = str(self.value))

class DiceRoller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameWin = tk.Tk()
        self.gameWin.title('Dice Roller')
        self.gameFrame = tk.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.dice = []
        self.Row1 = tk.Frame(self.gameWin)
        for i in range(1,4):
            self.dice.append(die(i, self.Row1))  
        self.topFrame = tk.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.rollBtn = tk.Button(self.topFrame,
            text = 'Roll Again',
            command = self.rollDice,
            font = ('Garamond', 56))
        self.rollBtn.pack(side = 'bottom')

        self.gameFrame.pack()
        self.Row1.pack()
        self.topFrame.pack()
        self.gameWin.mainloop()

    def rollDice(self):
        for die in self.dice:
            die.rollDice()

DiceRoller()
```