# Update label elements in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
import tkinter
from random import randint
score = 0
window = tkinter.Tk()

def Validate():
    global score
    answer_string = answer.get()
    try:
        answer_value = int(answer_string)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return

if answer_value == number1 * number2:
    score -= 1
    print('True')
    q.pack_forget()
else:
    score += 1
    print('False')
i=0
while i==0:
    number1 = randint(1,12)
    number2 = randint(1,12)
    q = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(number1) + "x" + str(number2) + " ?")
    q.pack()
    answer = tkinter.Entry(window)
    submit = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Submit", command=Validate)
    answer.pack()
    submit.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the text in q every time a question is asked. What I'm trying to do is remove q inside the validate function and then re-create it every time the code loops, but that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this addresses what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update. You don't need to recreate the label each time, just update it.

Comment: What is the new string you try to create?

Comment: I'm trying to update the q string  q = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(number1) + "x" + str(number2) + " ?")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you don't need to create the Label each iteration, there are several ways of how to update Label in tkinter.

For example:

**1.**

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.StringVar()
text.set('old')
lb = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=text)
...
text.set('new')
```

**2.**

```
lb = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(number1) + "x" + str(number2) + " ?")
lb['text'] = 'new'
```

**3.**

```
lb = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(number1) + "x" + str(number2) + " ?")
lb.config(text='new')
```