# Making a label remove after a set time TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, tkinter, python-3.5

My code currently checks the username and password entered my the user and then returns to the label with the corresponding text.

As shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

def Login():
    global AnameEL
    global ApwordEL # More globals :D
    global ArootA
    global f1
    global f2

    ArootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
    ArootA.geometry('1280x720')
    ArootA.title('Admin login') # This makes the window title 'login'

    f1 = Frame(width=200, height=200, background="#D3D3D3")
    f2 = Frame(ArootA, width=400, height=200)

    f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
    f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

    AnameL = Label(f2, text='Username: ') # More labels
    ApwordL = Label(f2, text='Password: ') # ^
    AnameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    ApwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    AnameEL = Entry(f2) # The entry input
    ApwordEL = Entry(f2, show='*')
    AnameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ApwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    AloginB = Button(f2, text='Login', command=CheckLogin) # This makes the login button, which will go to the CheckLogin def.
    AloginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    ArootA.mainloop()

def CheckLogin():
    checkP = Label(f2, text='')
    checkP.grid(row=3, column=1)
    if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123": # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
        checkP.config(text='sucess')

    else:
        checkP.config(text='fail')

Login()
```

I would like to add another feature where after 2 seconds new lines of code are ran depending on the login failed/success.

For example when the user enters a wrong login I would like the text "fail" to disappear after 2 seconds and if the user enters the correct password I would like a new function to be ran after 2 seconds of the "success" being displayed.

So I tried this:
(also importing time at the top of my code)

```
if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123": # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
    checkP.config(text='sucess')
    time.sleep(2)
    nextpage()
else:
    checkP.config(text='fail')
    time.sleep(2)
    checkP.config(text='')

def nextpage():
    f1.destroy()
```

However, this wasn't successful. After the login button was pressed it waited 2 seconds and then ran nextpage() instead of displaying "success" for 2 seconds and then running nextpage() and for incorrect logins it goes straight to         `checkP.config(text='')` after 2 seconds of the button press.

How can I resolve this?

All help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update root before using `time.sleep()`. Additionally, since you are dealing with a GUI, you should prefer using timers over pausing execution. In this case, Tkinter's own `after()` function should be preferred over `time.sleep()`, because it simply places the event on the event queue as opposed to pausing execution.

> **after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)**
>
> Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.

So, per your example:

```
if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123":
    checkP.config(text='sucess')
    ArootA.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    nextpage()
else:
    checkP.config(text='fail')
    ArootA.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    nextpage()
```

With `after()`:

```
if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123":
    checkP.config(text='sucess')
    ArootA.after(2000, nextpage)
else:
    checkP.config(text='fail')
    ArootA.after(2000, lambda : checkP.config(text=''))
```

You may also want to take a look at alternative ways to update the values of labels to avoid having to update root while you are in the mainloop (e.g. [Making python/tkinter label widget update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update)).

Comment: If you're using `after`, you don't need to call `update()`. Also, you're using `after` incorrectly. You must pass `after` a _reference_ to a function. You're immediately calling the function and giving `after` the _result_ of the function. It needs to be `ArootA.after(2000, nextpage)`

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I thought `after()` didn't need `update()` but couldn't get it to run without `update()`. Forgot to remove the parentheses! Updated the answer. Good catch.