# How to update a Tkinter label after changing variable that is linked to the label?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.state=("zoomed")
counter = 0
word = ("Placeholder")

lbl_point = Label(root, text="Points: " + counter
lbl_point.pack

txt_guess = Entry(root, text="You're guess?")
txt_guess.pack(side=TOP)

if txt_guess.get() == word:
 counter = counter + 1
 print("debug" + counter)
else:
 print("placeholder incorrect")

root.mainloop()
```

The label "lbl_point" doesn't update when "counter" changes numbers.
I've tried adding `root.update_idletasks()` at the end of `"if txt_guess.get() == word`
but it didn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making python/tkinter label widget update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update)

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Comment: Been a long time but I finally read through event-driver programming and I see where I went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution:

```
lbl_point.configure(text="Points: " + counter)
```