# Executing concurrently to tkinter.mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI using tkinter which has a refreshing display. I have this code,

```
while True:
    val= randint(1,50)
```

And this is the loop for my GUI,

```
label2= Label(root, text= val , font=("Helvetica", 60))
label2.place(relx=0.53, rely=0.44, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

These two do not seem to work simultaneously. The one placed above the other one executes first which is an infinite loop so it never reaches **"root.mainloop()"**. I want to update the label content constantly. How do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005)

Comment: Either put the while loop in a thread task, or use `after()` to replace the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix it using this,

```
while True:
    val= randint(1,50)
    label2.config(text=val)
    label2.after(200, self.get_upvotes)

label2= Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 60))
label2.place(relx=0.53, rely=0.33, anchor=CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use `Tk.After(delay,callback)`. You can wrap the while loop in a function, and use it as the callback.

For example:

```
def f():
    val.set(randint(1,50))
    root.after(1,f)

#Later
root.after(1, f)
root.mainloop()
```

One thing that will also need to change is how you're setting val in Label. It should be `textvariable=val` instead of `text=val`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I  tried placing the **While**  loop inside a function and then calling it.


`def f():
    while True:
        val= randint(1,50)
        time.sleep(3)

root.after(2000, f)


root.mainloop()`

But it doesn't seem to work. The program never reaches **root.mainloop** due to the infinite **While loop** due to which the GUI Window never displays anything.

Comment: Is the window popping up an doesn't have anything on it, or does the window not even pop up?

Comment: The window is popping up but doesn't have anything on it.

Comment: This is a matter of updating the variable inside of the while loop. I can take a look on how to do that, don't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, please... That'd be of great help. I have also tried the **val= StringVar()** and **val.set('something')** for updating the label content but the problem sticks around the Infinite While I Guess.

Comment: I was wrong before, the window not popping up was probably something to due with Tkinter scheduling the updates of the window, with it waiting for functions called with `root.after()` to finish. I made an edit where the function is called recursively and updates the variable.

Comment: `root.after(1, f)` attempts to run `f` 1000 times per second. While you can attempt to do that, tkinter won't be able to keep up.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, tkinter will schedule screen updates after each one, so updating shouldn't be a problem