# Tkinter - problem with labels overlaying each other

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on Music player and when I play a new song I always call songInfoDisplay function. As you can see on the picture (link below) songs information are not displayed properly. Is there a way how to fix it? Thank you for your time and answers.

```
master = Tk()
def playSong():
        song = lb.get(ACTIVE)
        pathToSong = (path + "\\" + song)
        mixer.music.load(pathToSong)
        mixer.music.play()
        audio = MP3(pathToSong)
        songLength = int(audio.info.length)
        songInfo=mutagen.File(pathToSong, easy=True)     
        songInfoDisplay()

def songInfoDisplay():

    songLabel=Label(master, text=songInfo["title"])
    artistLabel=Label(master, text=songInfo["artist"])
    albumLabel=Label(master, text=songInfo["album"])

    artistLabel.grid(row=5, column=3, stick=E)
    songLabel.grid(row=6, column=3, stick=E)
    albumLabel.grid(row=7, column=3, stick=E)
```

Comment: You should not create those labels inside `songInfoDisplay()` function.  Create them once the program starts and update their text inside `songInfoDisplay()` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005)

Comment: @acw1668 I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Could you post example?

Answer (score 1):

You should create those labels once when program starts, then update their text when a song is selected.  Below is a modified example based on your code:

```
master = Tk()

# create the required labels
songLabel=Label(master)
artistLabel=Label(master)
albumLabel=Label(master)

artistLabel.grid(row=5, column=3, stick=E)
songLabel.grid(row=6, column=3, stick=E)
albumLabel.grid(row=7, column=3, stick=E)

def playSong():
        song = lb.get(ACTIVE)
        pathToSong = (path + "\\" + song)
        mixer.music.load(pathToSong)
        mixer.music.play()
        audio = MP3(pathToSong)
        songLength = int(audio.info.length)
        songInfo=mutagen.File(pathToSong, easy=True)     
        songInfoDisplay(songInfo) # pass songInfo to songInfoDisplay()

def songInfoDisplay(songInfo):
    # show the song information
    songLabel.config(text=songInfo["title"][0])
    artistLabel.config(text=songInfo["artist"][0])
    albumLabel.config(text=songInfo["album"][0])
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Even those curly brackets are gone :) Thank you very much!