# Not Displaying the Keyboard Inputs as Labels in the Window in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, label

How can I display the letters entered from the keyboard as labels in the gui window? 
I can only view it on the console right now.

```
from tkinter import*  
from tkinter import ttk 
window = Tk()

def letter(event):
    a=str(print (repr(event.char)," key pressed."))

    label=Label(window,text=a)
    label.place(x=15,y=15)


def clicked(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print(event.x,event.y ,"coordinate clicked.")

frame =Frame(window, width=500, height=500)
frame.bind("<Key>",letter)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", clicked) 
frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems with your code.

1. **What do you think `str(print (repr(event.char)," key pressed."))` returns?** It returns a None value which is then put into the label and the label is showing "None".
2. In the function `letter` you are creating a `Label` every time the function is called, which means it is just overlapping the label on a label created before. So create one label outside the function and then update that label into that function.

---

*Complete code:*

```py
from tkinter import*  
from tkinter import ttk 

window = Tk()

def letter(event):
    a = "'%s' key pressed" %event.char
    print(a)
    # Update the text of label.
    label['text'] = a

def clicked(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print(event.x,event.y ,"coordinate clicked.")

frame =Frame(window, width=500, height=500)
frame.bind("<Key>",letter)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", clicked) 
frame.pack()

label=Label(window, text='Key')
label.place(x=15, y=15)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @murt: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the outlined checkmark.