# Tkinter GUI buttons running loops

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to use TKinter to make GUI for Python apps. I'm trying to create a Pomodoro timer, however I've encountered a couple of issues.

1. I run `while` loop in another function to update label with time left
2. While in loop GUI unresponsive (that's OK)
3. I've googled a little bit, went through some StackOverflow questions and I've found that this function running loop could be run in a separate thread.

This solved the first issue, but there is another

1. Cancel button works, but I don't see the click animation.
2. Timer does not stop immediately.

Can you kindly explain why this is happening and what I can do to increase the responsiveness of my GUI?

```
import time
import tkinter
import winsound
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import threading


def run_thread():
    global stop
    stop = False
    start_timer_btn.grab_release()
    threading.Thread(target=countdown()).start()


def stop_timer():
    global stop
    stop = True


def countdown():
    option = combo.get()
    if option == "25":
        seconds = 1500
    elif option == "15":
        seconds = 900
    # elif option == "2":
    #   countdown(300)
    # elif option == "3":
    #   countdown(1200)
    global stop
    while seconds and not stop:
        seconds -= 1
        print("minutes", seconds // 60, "seconds", seconds % 60)
        timer_label.configure(text=str(seconds // 60) + ":" + str(seconds % 60))
        window.update()
        time.sleep(1)
    winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)


stop = False
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("POMODORO Timer")
window.geometry("300x250")

combo = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window)
combo["values"] = [25, 15]
combo.current(1)

timer_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="00:00")
start_timer_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Start timer", bg="green", fg="white", command=run_thread)
stop_timer_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Stop timer", bg="red", fg="white", command=stop_timer)

combo.grid(row=1, column=0)
start_timer_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
stop_timer_btn.grid(row=1, column=2)
timer_label.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759) and [making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally discouraged to use sleep() especially when multithreading. Sleep waits 'at least' some time,but code execution may not restart due to other processes. This is what the documentation says:

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of
>   seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a
>   more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than
>   that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep()
>   following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the
>   suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount
>   because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: The function now sleeps at least secs even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler
>   raises an exception (see PEP 475 for the rationale).

The alternative is to use the .after() method. Here are some links:

[tkinter and time.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/tkinter-and-time-sleep)

[How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-to-create-a-timer-using-tkinter)

Comment: Thanks I will go through the articles and get back :)
P.S. from what you've cited seems indeed its not a good idea to use sleep.

Comment: Nice job, thumbs up.

Comment: if you dont mind can i ask 1 more thing please?

why if i call threading.Thread(target=playsound).start() - it works, but if i call it like this:threading.Thread(target=playsound()).start() - seems that it indefinitely loops? If i call timer function like this it just roll down to 0 instantly and throws and error that maximum iteration depth reached or something like this. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I never worked with threading, but this seems syntactical: `target=func` versus `target=func()`. In the first example the function is *passed* where in the second example the function is *called*. See also the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread