# Label Not Continually Updating Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-text

I have read through several answers to similar topics but none of them are relevant to my situation, I am trying to display a list on a label and whenever the button is pressed to update the list the label should update as well but it only updates when `submitbtn_name` is clicked. Any help appreciated I am very new to Tkinter.
My Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Path Creator")
root.geometry('1680x1080')
root['background'] = '#aaaaaa'

list_of_paths_list = []
path_list = []


name = Entry(root, width=400)
name.insert(0, "Name")
name.pack()

def add_name():
    path_list.append(name.get())
    list_label = Label(root, text="path name:" + str(path_list))
    list_label.pack()

submitbtn_name = Button(root, text="submit name", command=add_name)
submitbtn_name.pack()

value1 = Entry(root, width=400)
value1.insert(0, "value1")
value1.pack()

distance1 = Entry(root, width=400)
distance1.insert(0, "distance1")
distance1.pack()

def submitbtn_value_dist():
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(value1.get())
    temp_list.append(distance1.get())
    path_list.append(tuple(temp_list))
    list_label = Label(root, text="current path: " + path_list)
    list_label.pack()

submitbtn_pathpart = Button(root, text="submit path part", )
submitbtn_pathpart.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The only other button is `submitbtn_pathpart`, but it doesn't have a `command` to call when it's clicked.

Comment: `text="current path: " + path_list` needs to be `text="current path: " + str(path_list)`

Comment: Did you forget to add `command=submitbtn_value_dist` to the second button?

Comment: @Barmar, yup that was it. thanks for the help. Do you know why it isn't updating when I change the values and click the second btn again

Comment: You're not updating anything with either button, you keep creating new `Label`s.

Comment: @Barmar how would i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update

Comment: @Barmar I still don't understand how I would do that, you should set the text to a variable and change it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it better than the simple example in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Using f-string format. Added command in `submitbtn_pathpart`

Snippet:

```
def submitbtn_value_dist():
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(value1.get())
    temp_list.append(distance1.get())
    path_list.append(tuple(temp_list))
    list_label = Label(root, text=f"current path:{path_list}")
    list_label.pack()

submitbtn_pathpart = Button(root, text="submit path part", command=submitbtn_value_dist )
submitbtn_pathpart.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Output for name:

[image]

Output for value and distance:

[image]